# bring the left image to the right in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to bring the left image to the right, but I can not do it.
I know that I can use `Layout_Direction="rtl"` But I do not want to use it. On some phones, Layout is damaged

[image]

this is my layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/icon_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_front"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillAfter="false"
                android:fillEnabled="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_profile"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/message_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="People Name"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="some new text for new items"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_10" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So How can I put the image on the right? Also, the gravity does not work I tried the use of gravity but did not move the image to the right

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` is inside a `RelativeLayout`, so you need to add this atribute:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

or if you don't need RTL support:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and the xml will be:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_profile"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```